# Order Custom post type loop by custom field (datepicker)

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, order

I know there are a lot of articles and documentation on this but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a custom post type 'agenda' wich is made for events.
I want to sort this by the eventdate.
For this, I made a custom field (datepicker) using the [ACF plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

I've found some documentation on the ACF website wich learned me how to echo the date in dutch format and also an article about sorting the posts by custom meta value.
But I can't get it to work.

The key for my custom field is: datum_agenda

Codes I have already tried ( in the $args of the loop):

```
'orderby' => 'datum_agenda'
```

&

```
'meta_key'      => 'datum_agenda',
'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
'order'         => 'DESC'
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Seems like my code can't seem to find my meta_key or something because it still sorts by the autovalue.. (the normal post date)

Comment: Thanks @maartje! IF YOU HAVE A DRAG AND DROP POST SORTER INSTALLED, IT OVERRIDES THE DATE SORT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach should in my mind actually work, you do it like this:

**Code:**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'agenda',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'datum_agenda',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

There are two pages at the ACF documentation you might want to read: [Date Picker](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/date-picker/) and [Order posts by custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/). Besides that the only thing that comes to mind would be *how is the date formated* and might the problem originate there, having `yymmdd` as value for the ACF »Date Picker« field »Save format« is recommended.

Comment: -.- Stupid stupid stupid, I added your code and it still didn't work..
Later I wanted to install a plugin to drag and drop them in a correct order, but I found out it was already installed.
That plugin overruled the query.
Thanks for your help anyway, but the readon it didn't work was because I had that plugin activated..

Comment: Yes, beware the quirks coming with some plugins...but on the other hand, you've figured it out now. @Maartje

Comment: whenever I use 'meta_key', returned list becomes empty

Comment: @MurhafSousli I don't know what the reason could be. My answer is compliant with the official usage of `WP_Query` - take a look at [Codex: WP_Query - Order + Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). So I'm guessing something else, e.g. some other parameter(s), must be wrong in your setup.