# Sort custom post type by custom datepicker instead of filtering

Tags: custom-post-types, sort, datepicker

I have a custom post type Event that I use in conjunction with ACF. I have a group called event and inside that group I have a field called date_start. And this is the code that I currently have, but it filters instead of sorts, meaning every past event is not visible.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date_start' ,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => current_time('Ymd'),
            )
            ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date_start',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Also, I have tried this code to no avail from a similar [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133512/order-custom-post-type-loop-by-custom-field-datepicker) here.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num ',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date_start',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Doing `meta_value_num date` instead `meta_value_num` didn't product desired result either. So, my question is, is there a way to sort these events and not filter theme, so every event would be visible and the most current would be displayed first.

Any help or ideas is much appreciated.

## Update

adding `'type' => 'DATE',` to `meta-query` didn't solve the problem.

Here is the `var_dump($post);`

```
object(WP_Post)[7713]
  public 'ID' => int 974
  public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'post_date' => string '2020-01-16 13:40:21' (length=19)
  public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2020-01-16 13:40:21' (length=19)
  public 'post_content' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_title' => string '24 - 25 февраля' (length=22)
  public 'post_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
  public 'comment_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
  public 'ping_status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
  public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_name' => string '24-25-fevralya' (length=14)
  public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_modified' => string '2020-01-16 13:40:21' (length=19)
  public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2020-01-16 13:40:21' (length=19)
  public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post_parent' => int 0
  public 'guid' => string 'http://emtway.local/?post_type=events&#038;p=974' (length=48)
  public 'menu_order' => int 5
  public 'post_type' => string 'events' (length=6)
  public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `meta_query`, you missed the type of the field:

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'events',
'posts_per_page' => '-1',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date_start' ,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => current_time('Ymd'),
        'type' => 'DATE',
    )
),
'meta_key' => 'event_date_start',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

);

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but it's still filtering instead of sorting.

Comment: Could you please var_dump() the result and post here?

Comment: I've added that to my question, but it doesn't contain the ACF fields.